# Return positions of onehot encoded vector in a compact np.array

Tags: numpy

If I have a one-hot encoded array of the following form:

```
arr

array([[[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

How can I retrieve the positions of ones? In particular, I would like to return something very simple like

```
array([[2,0,0],
       [0,6,7],
       [1,3,3],
       [6,0,0]] dtype=float32)
```

Comment: `arr.argmax(2)`? Please name the arrays in the example code.

Comment: was that so simple?!? Ahah many thanks!

Comment: If the last dimension is sufficiently big and performance matters, then please try a `np.where` loop. It should be very fast in recent versions of Numpy (especially in you case since the array contains a lot of zeros values).